# Why is NativeWind not showing the text with the colour red?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have installed nativeWind on the project, it only works correctly on the main HomeScreen.js, it is not showing th changes anywhere else. These are my project files:

**HomeScreen.js:**

```js
import { SafeAreaView, View, Text, Image, Platform, StatusBar, StyleSheet, TextInput, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import { useLayoutEffect } from 'react'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { AdjustmentsVerticalIcon, ChevronDownIcon, MagnifyingGlassIcon, UserIcon} from "react-native-heroicons/outline";
import { flex } from 'react-native-wind/dist/styles/flex/flex';
import Categories from '../Components/Categories';

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useLayoutEffect( () => {
      navigation.setOptions({
        headerShown: false,
      })
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView className='pt-8 bg-white'>
    <Text className='text-red-500\'>

      {/* Header */}
      <View className='flex-row items-center pb-3 mx-4 space-x-2  px-4'>
        <Image
          source={{
            uri: 'https://links.papareact.com/wru'
          }}
          className='h-9 w-9 bg-gray-300 p-4 rounded-full pt-3'
        />
        <View className="#00CCBB">
          <Text className='font-bold text-gray-400 text-xs'>Deliver now!</Text>
          <Text className='font-bold text-xl'>Current Location
            <ChevronDownIcon size={20} color="#00CCBB" />
            <UserIcon size={35} color='#00CCBB'/>
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      </Text>
      {/* Search */}
      <View className='flex-row items-center space-x-2 pb-2 mx-4 px-2'>
          <View className=' items-center flex-row space-x-2 bg-gray-200 p-3 flex-1'>
            <MagnifyingGlassIcon color="gray" size={20}/>
            <TextInput placeholder="Restraunts and cuisines" keyboardType="default"/>
          </View>
          <AdjustmentsVerticalIcon height={30} width={30} color='#00CCBB'/>
        </View>

        {/* Body */}
        <ScrollView 
        className='bg-gray-100'
        contentContainerStyle={{
            paddingBottom: 100,
        }}>
            {/* Categories */}
            <Categories />

            {/* Featured rows */}
        </ScrollView>

    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
export default HomeScreen
```

**Categories.js:**

```js
import { ScrollView, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import CardForCategories from './CardForCategories'

const Categories = () => {
  return (
    <ScrollView 
    contentContainerStyle={{
        paddingHorizontal: 15,
        paddingTop: 10,
    }}
    horizontal
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
        { /* CategoryCard */ }
            <CardForCategories title={"Meh 1 "} imgUrl="https://links.papareact.com/wru"/>
            <CardForCategories title={"Meh 2 "} imgUrl="https://links.papareact.com/wru"/>
            <CardForCategories title={"Meh 3 "} imgUrl="https://links.papareact.com/wru"/>
    </ScrollView>
  )
}

export default Categories
```

**CardForCategories.js:**

```js
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, Image } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const CardForCategories = ({imgUrl , title}) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity className='relative mr-2'>
      <Image source={{
        height:80,
        width:80,
        uri: imgUrl,
      }}
      className='rounded-full' />
      <Text className='text-red-500'>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default CardForCategories
```

The code works just fine on the HomeScreen.js file, but it doesn't work anywhere else, such as the CardForCategories.js, it doesn't show the changes

Answer (score 0):

i expect you have been find the solution.

However this is my solution. In nativewind you must pass the value in [ ].

```
text-[#ECADFF]
```

and not pass like tailwind as you passed in your component:

```
<Text className='text-red-500'>
```

Try change your 'text-red-500' for 'text-[#EF4444]'.

Also, if you're using expo, you should consider the next issue: https://github.com/marklawlor/nativewind/issues/312

Expo doesn't build correctly if you want pass dynamic values in your class styles. You can't build with this case, where textColor = [#fff]:

```
<Text className={`text-${textColor}`}>
```

You must pass the complete string:

```
<Text className={`${textColor}`}>
```

Where textColor = 'text-[#fff]'.